# Batch file to add number a number for specific location in a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

I have a batch file intended to add a number at a specific location in a text file.

For example:

```
A,B,C,D,1,07/2018,3,4
E,F,G,H,5,06/2019,7,8
I,J,K,L,9,10/2020,11,12
```

The output will be:

```
A,B,C,D,1,07/30/2018,3,4
E,F,G,H,5,06/30/2019,7,8
I,J,K,L,9,10/30/2020,11,12
```

**EDIT**

This is my code but it works only on end of each lines. But I need on specific location of the delims and add some text or numbers

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims=/" %%a in (oldfile.text) do echo ^%%a^/ >>newfile.text
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Comment: You can use a FOR /F command to read the file. You can then use the TOKENS and DELIMS options to split the line using the slash as the delimiter.

Comment: `(for /f "tokens=1* delims=/" %%a in (oldfile.text) do echo %%a/30/%%b) >newfile.text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example script, ran from the same directory as the example source file should work:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "SrcFile=oldfile.text"
Set "OutFile=newfile.text"
If Not Exist "%SrcFile%" Exit /B
(   For /F "UseBackQ EOL=, Tokens=1-6* Delims=," %%A In ("%SrcFile%"
    ) Do For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=/" %%H In ("%%F"
    ) Do Echo=%%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%H/30/%%I,%%G)>"%OutFile%"
```

*As required, change the source file name and output file name on lines `2` and `3` respectively.*

A very quick explanation:

The first`For`loop reads each source file line, splitting it into seven tokens using the comma as a delimiter. *(The first token being assigned as`%%A`, second as`%%B`, third as`%%C`, fourth as`%%D`, fifth as`%%E`, sixth as`%%F`, and everything after the sixth,`*`, to`%%G`.)*

We want to work with the content of the sixth token, i.e. `%%F`

The second`For`loop reads each string assigned as`%%F`, splitting it into two tokens using the forward slash as a delimiter. *(The first token being assigned as`%%H`, and everything after the first,`*`, to`%%I`)*

We want to place our new string`30/`in between tokens`%%H`and`%%I`adding back in the removed delimiters. *(`%%H/30/%%I`)*

We now want to place that modified sixth token`%%F`, *(`%%H/30/%%I`)*, back into the line adding in the removed delimiters. *(`%%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%H/30/%%I,%%G`)*

We want to write the output from the loops to our output file, so we enclose the loops inside parentheses and redirect to a new file using the standard redirection operator`>`

**Screenshot**
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hello i tried your code but It has output newfile.txt but no data inside.

Comment: Well the code works perfectly and has been tested on at least two different Windows operating system versions. You have either copied it incorrectly or have not run it against the file you used in the question. Please provide more information, exactly what you modified in the script I posted and exactly what the content of the file was that you ran it against.

Comment: Ow sorry it works now. I will mark your answer as an answer. Thank youuuuuuu!

Comment: hi mate. I just want to ask if i want to add if else statement where will I put

Comment: I don't follow you. An `Else` statement is conditional following an `If` statement; you're going to have to be more specific about what you're wanting to do.

Comment: For example from the code of yours. I want to do like this "IF %%H==01 Echo=%%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%H/30/%%I,%%G" and "IF %%H==02 Echo=%%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%H/31/%%I,%%G"

Comment: It looks like you're trying to implement a method of determining and adding `nn/`, instead of `30/`. i.e. Determine the last day of the month, `nn` based on the the value of `%%H` and also to some extent, the year, `%%I`, _due to leap years_. If so, this becomes a completely new question and deserves to be posted as such. It may also be worth adding a [powershell] tag to it because that has date object functionality, unlike batch files which work only with strings and poor integer math.

Comment: Its ok if its not leap year or leap year. I'll just adjust. May I know where can I put IF statement from your code? If you want me to make new question I will do so and I'll comment here the link. Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest you follow the advice given in my last comment. Please don't ask for a solution which requires manual adjustment afterwards, it's an almost pointless pursuit, ignoring leap years when it can be scripted into the solution. I also remind you to include a tag for `Powershell`, _(or `JScript` if preferred)_.